# How to create grok filter for logstash conf

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Dear Community Members,

I am new to grok. Following are the log message to which I want to extract fields values like :

```
Method :  createCabinet 
Argument : {"comments":....}
Result : <201 Created,Folder ....
Time  : 21611 msec
CorrelationId : 00905cda-10a0-4793-8b77-e1dba05dcb2c
```

Log Message :

> 16:43:45.159 [http-nio-8183-exec-9] INFO 
>   com.newgen.aspect.LoggingAspect - Method : createCabinet | Argument :
>   {"comments":"Default cabinet precreated by
>   system","ownerName":"manoj","usedFor":"general","folderName":"Cabinet80704183","ownerId":"AVlFxAVOoeDBAMtAMzee","folderType":"cabinet"}{"bytes":[49,50,51,52,53],"empty":false}
>   | Result : <201 Created,Folder [id=5cac7e618dd9854e78007736,
>   folderName=Cabinet80704183, folderType=cabinet, comments=Default
>   cabinet precreated by system, parentFolderId=null, ownerName=manoj,
>   ownerId=AVlFxAVOoeDBAMtAMzee, creationDateTime=Tue Apr 09 16:43:34 IST
>   2019, revisedDateTime=null, accessDateTime=null, usedFor=general,
>   version=0, metadataId=null, tenantId=12345],{}> | Time : 21611 msec |
>   CorrelationId : 00905cda-10a0-4793-8b77-e1dba05dcb2c

I am debugging this on  https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com
So far unable to construct the required grok filter for logstash. Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? Can you update your question with your current grok?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%{TIME:timestamp} \[%{NOTSPACE}\] %{NOTSPACE:log_level} %{NOTSPACE:class} \- Method \: %{NOTSPACE:method} \| Argument \: %{GREEDYDATA:argument} \| Result \: %{GREEDYDATA:result} \| Time \: %{NUMBER:time_ms} msec \| CorrelationId \: %{NOTSPACE:correlation_id}
```

tested on Logstash 6.7